# AdoJobStore with Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, quartz.net

I was finally able to setup `ADOJobStore` for Sql Server, but I would also like it to work with *Sqlite* and  I am still yet to get it to work. This is the part of my `quartz.config` that I set the properties for my `AdoJobStore`:

```
# to use the sqlite store, uncomment all of this 
quartz.jobStore.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz 
quartz.jobStore.dataSource = default 
quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString = Data Source=postbag-jobs.db;Version=3;Foreign Keys=ON;
quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_ 
quartz.jobStore.clustered = false
quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz 
quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.StdAdoDelegate, Quartz 
quartz.dataSource.default.provider = SQLite-10 
quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
```

I have created the Sqlite database separately and have placed it inside the working directory of my server. When the service initializes however, I get a `SchedulerException` that says:

```
Could not Initialize DataSource: default
```

With this `InnerException`:

```
Error while reading metadata information for provider 'SQLite-10'
Parameter name: providerName
```

Do I have to provide my server with Sqlite `.DLL`? Because I didn't need to do that for Sql Server.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to use **Sqlite** with **Quartz.net** you have to use these keys:

```
<add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value="true" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="default" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="qrtz_" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SQLiteDelegate, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.dataSource.default.provider" value="SQLite-10" />
<add key="quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString" value="Data Source=postbag-jobs.db;Version=3;" />
```

I have noticed that your **driverDelegateType** key is not the right one. You should use **SQLiteDelegate**:

```
<add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SQLiteDelegate, Quartz" />
```

You need to install the [ADO.NET provider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/) as well (**nuget**):

```
Install-Package System.Data.SQLite.Core
```

Another problem you might have is the compatibility with your provider (**1.0.94.0**) and that one defined in Quartz.Net (**1.0.88.0**). You can find info [here](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/Impl/AdoJobStore/Common/dbproviders.properties#L250).

To fix this just add this section to your **app.config**:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite" publicKeyToken="db937bc2d44ff139" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.88.0" newVersion="1.0.94.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

A working example can be found [here](https://github.com/Leftyx/QuartzNetAdoJobStoreSQLite) on github.

Comment: thank you! I will test it as soon as i can and come back to you. Makes sense!

Comment: No worries. I've added a working example. See update. Cheers.

Comment: @Pedram: Feel free to accept/upvote this answer if it's good for you :-)

Comment: sorry @LeftyX, I was dragged to another project suddenly. I will test this as soon as I am back on this. I haven't forgotten that.

Comment: This worked for me except that I had to set the provider to "SQLite"

Comment: Remove ["org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true" if you want to pass object in the JobDataMap while calling the sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger) function because otherwise it throws Quartz.JobPersistenceException